# Set element to top of all layers in canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

I'm using KonvaJS to create a canvas which can connect 'nodes' by using 'connections'. I created 2 `Layers`, one `NodeLayer` and one `ConnectionLayer`. I always want to render the `NodeLayer` on top of the `ConnectionLayer`. So they're rendered as followed:

```
<Stage>
    <ConnectionLayer />
    <NodeLayer />
</Stage>
```

This makes sure that the Nodes are always rendered on top of the connections. I'm trying to add a tooltip on my connections, but because the `NodeLayer` is on top of the `connectionLayer` the tooltip wont show when it's positioned behind a node.

Is there a way to render the tooltip on top of nodes from within the `connectionLayer` while not changing the order of the layers?

Comment: Maybe use HTML to show the tooltip, have a notification layer, or tell the node layer to render the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As mentioned in the comment, you can try to use HTML for the tooltip and position it on top of the canvas with absolute position.
2. Or you can create a special component for displaying the tooltip and place it on top of all components:

```
<Stage>
    <ConnectionLayer />
    <NodeLayer />
    {this.state.tooltip && <TooltipLayer />}
</Stage>
```

3. Or you can try to move the tooltip node MANUALLY into another top layer. That method is basically not recommended with `react-konva` but it may work in many cases (I used it by myself in production app).

```
const Tooltip = () => {

  const groupRef = React.useRef();

  // move it when the component is mounted
  React.useEffect(() => {
     const stage = groupRef.current.getStage();
     const topLayer = stage.children[stage.children.length - 1];
     groupRef.current.moveTo(topLayer);
  }, []);

  return <Group ref={groupRef} />
}
```